# docker cannot start MYSQL service

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

does anyone have any idea about this error? I am trying to deploy a swarm stack with **mysql:8** image and I got this error the MySQL service stopped and not started.
kindly check the DB service below

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/app
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
     replicas: 5
     restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure   

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:    
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ROUTE
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 2020
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 2020
      MYSQL_USER: sqluser
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
     replicas: 3    
     restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure  
        
networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
    driver: overlay
    
volumes:
  db:
```

[image: mysql service logs image]

Comment: What's the actual error message?  The image file you've included here is very hard to read (impossible for some people) and hard to search for.  Is this just a question about running a database, or is there relevant application source code you can include?

Comment: @DavidMaze if you click the image and click on the zoom-in button you will see clearly, anyway this is the error in the logs [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple instances of MySQL trying to write to the same database on disk is asking for trouble. That's why the first instance you start locks a file on the disk, so any subsequent instances will fail.

It's by design that what you're doing fails.

Comment: Yes that's right sir thanks for the information, but what is the best solution for this case? I need 3 replicas for my DB instance